# mysql checking permission by partition

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, administration

I was dropping large partitioned table (500 partitions) and I noticed that state was checking permission almost all the time.

Does MySql checks permission before dropping every partition?
Did MySql checked permission in my case 500 times?

Here is show profile

- 'starting','0.000061'
- 'checking permissions','674.576028'
- 'query end','0.000111'
- 'closing tables','0.000043'
- 'freeing items','0.000068'
- 'logging slow query','0.000006'
- 'logging slow query','0.000102'
- 'cleaning up','0.002764'

Comment: DBAs would be in a lot better position to answer this question than sw developers. Therefore I voted to migrate this question to the DBA site.